# Free service to send WhatsApp and/or SMS alerts

Tags: notification, sms, whatsapp

I am looking forward to notify my customers about the status of their application. I want to send them a WhatsApp alert and/or an SMS to notify them that the status of their application has changed from "pending" to "completed".

So, can you please suggest me a free/inexpensive service to accomplish this?